# How to convert current webpage to a text file?

Tags: python, html, text-files

I have created one plugin and we need current  webpage in the form of  plain text file so that we can use that text file as an input to the plugin .How do I do it??

Comment: in which language u want to do it?

Comment: I am using python as the backend program

Comment: @Anusha, I suggest tagging the question with your language of choice in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
url = "http://google.com"
text = urllib.open(url)
```